# Grant Select on some columns for specific user

Tags: sql-server, select, permissions

I have a windows group with 20 people and all 20 people in the group were revoked access for some columns in the table. Now I need to add the select permissions for 2 of the users in this windows group. How can I do this?
Can I simply grant select on these columns directly to these 2 users instead of windows group?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you give permissions only required users in SQL Server using `GRANT` like this

`GRANT SELECT ON <schema>.<tablename>(<Col1>,<Col2>) TO [Domain\User]`

For more info, refer [Grant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx)